# Rails' MVC vs Microsoft MVC - where to put logics?

Tags: mvc, asp.net-mvc, ruby-on-rails, model

Some time ago I switched from Microsoft ASP.NET 2.0 (WebForms, never knew Microsoft's MVC) to Ruby on Rails and learned it's MVC approach, after which some things in ASP.NET MVC seem to be weird.

In RoR the best practice is to put the model logics (various ORM queries) to a model. I noticed that programmers seem to avoid this in ASP.NET MVC. What is the best place to put ORM (Entity Framework) queries? Controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Microsoft version of MVC, you have the heavy Controller implementation instead of the heavy Model implementation that a large portion of the development community uses.

The ORM should be a part of the Model layer, but a lot of Microsoft documentation has Entity Framework (which is their ORM) throughout the Controllers.

In a lot of ways, it makes sense to have a very limited Model with a heavy Controller. All of your business logic is in one layer (the Controller).  Your Model objects become nothing more than a transport object for data. This makes for a simpler separation of concerns.

However, the rest of the dev community really seems to prefer the heavy Model. The Controller acts as a dispatch system for smarter data objects.

[From Microsoft's Overview of MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

> > - **Models.** Model objects are the parts of the application that implement the logic for the application's data domain. Often, model objects retrieve and store model state in a database. For example, a Product object might retrieve information from a database, operate on it, and then write updated information back to a Products table in a SQL Server database.
> >
> >   In small applications, the model is often a conceptual separation instead of a physical one. For example, if the application only reads a dataset and sends it to the view, the application does not have a physical model layer and associated classes. In that case, the dataset takes on the role of a model object.
> > - **Views.** Views are the components that display the application's user interface (UI). Typically, this UI is created from the model data. An example would be an edit view of a Products table that displays text boxes, drop-down lists, and check boxes based on the current state of a Product object.
> > - **Controllers.** Controllers are the components that handle user interaction, work with the model, and ultimately select a view to render that displays UI. In an MVC application, the view only displays information; the controller handles and responds to user input and interaction. For example, the controller handles query-string values, and passes these values to the model, which in turn might use these values to query the database.

Comment: `The ORM should be a part of the Model layer, but a lot of Microsoft documentation has Entity Framework (which is their ORM) throughout the Controllers.` -- That statement is a bit misleading.  Your controllers are going to have to touch the model eventually.  That's true whether you're touching the Data Access Layer directly (in the case of EF or some other ORM), or indirectly via a Business Layer or Service Layer (also part of the model).

Answer (score 0):

The Model is everything that is not in a View or a Controller.  That includes the ORM, regardless of whether it is Ruby on Rails, ASP.NET MVC or some other flavor of MVC.

Comment: Indeed too short of an answer but not worth a downvote because it's a correct one. Where to put the logic in MVC is a decision that falls on the developer, not the framework. The whole question is a bit silly.

Comment: Since when has brevity become a criteria for a downvote?